# Is there a way to list all available commands in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, zsh

Is there a way to list all available commands in terminal?

I know linux has `compgen -c` is there an equivalent command for OS X?

**Update:**
The actual issue was that I was using zsh instead of bash. So from zsh, I could either just open `bash` or run a bash command from zsh `bash -c "compgen -c"`

Comment: Assuming your shell is bash then `compgen -c` will work.

Comment: maybe it is because I am using zsh I am getting `zsh: command not found: compgen`

Comment: yep, if I enter `bash` then `compgen -c` it works, I guess my question should have been what it the zsh equivalent to the bash command `compgen -c`

Comment: so I think if you are using zsh and have tweaked your default shell on a Mac then you must already be quite an advanced user :)

Comment: I'm starring your question, because even though it was "is there a way to list..."  it is always interesting to come back & see what other people are using the command line for on OSX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `zsh` you need to enable the completion system. Please read through `man zshcompsys`. To install the completion system enter the command

```
compinstall
```

and follow the directions. Check the `fpath` variable

```
echo $fpath
```

in my situation I needed to declare the variable in my .zshrc

```
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh/5.0.7/functions)
```

This is the location of my `zsh functions`. After the `compinit` line in your `.zshrc` add the following lines

```
autoload -Uz bashcompinit
bashcompinit
```

This is the completions entries in my `.zshrc`

```
#\\\_ COMPLETIONS _///#
zstyle :compinstall filename '/Users/fd0/.zshrc'
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(@s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
autoload -Uz bashcompinit
bashcompinit
```

I can now enter the command `compgen -c` and it behaves similar to `bash`.

Answer (score 6):

Just tap the **Tab** key twice (<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>).  You'll be prompted if you want to see all possible commands.  Tap **y** and you'll be presented with a list.

You can do that same thing for individual commands to see all options for that specific command.

Comment: Good note, but this only works for me if I already have a partial string in place and even then it's a bit different:`tab` x 1 displays if there are a few options, if there are a lot I have to confirm; more `tab` strikes cycles through options (maybe my zsh version 5.8 or configuration are different?). In any case, compgen is _command_ that generates completions as output. `tab` sequences are key bindings, not an "equivalent _command_".

Comment: This doesn't work in Z shell (native config) and I've been unable to configure it so.  It used to iirc in bash tho...  That said, in Z shell you can use the `which ` or `whence ` or `where ` commands followed by a `<space>` then hit the `<tab>` key to get prompted to see all possible listings (via `&PATH`)

Answer (score 4):

Like fd0 commented above, the best source for quickly listing most everything you can do in the Terminal, is by using the ***Bash*** **builtin** [compgen](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html).

***`Compgen`*** interfaces with the "completion" function in Bash, so it is intended to keep a list of most everything you can do in the shell.  So it is interesting that **technically compgen is listing commands, aliases, and functions, as well as a few other things like builtins, variables, groups, jobs and service names.**  My experience is that it will not list everthing, like applications typcially ran in the GUI, which I will mention below.  You can use the ***`open`*** command in OSX for quite a few things, for example.

`compgen -c` executes the command in a subshell environment, and its output is used as the possible completions, which is probably what you want. If **Bash** if your shell, it will spew out similar information for all commands or a single command if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

It's also common in ***OSX*** that many programs can be executed from the shell, so many program names that you'll find in ***/Applications*** can also be called via a CLI from the shell.  Similarly, many programs are (at least) at ***/Applications/Utilities***, some interesting stuff is at ***/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications*** (as well as other things under the /System main directory...), and as well sometimes custom programs get put under the classic Unix locations like /usr/bin, usr/local/bin, /opt, and /sys/bin.

Often you can find other interesting things to type, probably also covered above, by typing `help` or `help [command or argument]`, with more information about most programs or builtins coming with `info [command]` or `man [command].`  `Apropos` is also quite interesting, which you may know already.  These things will get most everything, I imagine there are other things one just needs, or should, hack around and discover...

Answer (score -1):

While in Terminal, type <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then you'll see:

`Display all 1653 possibilities? (y or n).`

Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and it will list all possible commands

Comment: In my case, pressing tab inserts tab. So this probably depends on the Terminal being used.

Comment: How is this answer different from the answer I left 2 years before your answer?

Answer (score -1):

(Tab, Tab) does the trick, but it only works on bash, if it doesn't work firstly just type 'bash' then (Tab, Tab) then you have an option of yes(y) or no(n) then you are fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Instead of repeating the same info from two previous answers, it would've been best to edit one of them with 'just type bash'.